# Issue with 500 Errors

Tags: wordpress, cpu-usage

I have Wordpress installed on my website (not Wordpress.com). For the last week, I've been getting 500 errors when trying to connect to any site I have set up and my host keeps saying that I need to have my site "optimized" because some of the scripts are getting hung up in the CPU usage. They aren't telling me which scripts or what exactly is happening to know even where to begin.

I've updated all of my plugins, themes, and Wordpress versions. I've deleted plugins and themes I'm not using, and optimized the MySQL database tables. None of this is making a difference.

This issue has cropped up before and they were eventually able to fix it, but the constant run around meant it took far more time than it should have. Unfortunately, they aren't very forthcoming with the reasons for the issue and keep saying that they have to limit server resources since I'm using a shared service.

Essentially, it feels like they want me to find a web designer who will inspect all of my "code" to optimize it. Except that it's all Wordpress and the only thing I've made any adjustments to are CSS style formatting. I don't know php, so I haven't made any php adjustments to any files.

Here are the last several entries from the error log. I'm afraid they don't make any sense to me and the techs at my host don't seem like they care to enlighten me as to what they mean (probably because they don't know).

Long story short (too late), I'm hoping someone here can give me an idea where I need to look to try and figure out what the problem is (if the error log is even telling me anything with regard to the script hang up issues). Several of these look like identical issues almost like a spider is trying to crawl the site, but is erroring out and keeps trying and is causing a perpetual loop trying to access the same pages. Or maybe I'm misreading what it all means.

[Wed Apr 12 14:47:32.224444 2023] [autoindex:error] [pid 789949:tid 23391127324416] [client 172.187.192.35:55646] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home2/cinemasi/public_html/ofta/wp-admin/css/: No matching DirectoryIndex (ikonboard.cgi,index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: binance.com
[Wed Apr 12 14:45:41.462155 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 789949:tid 23391110514432] [client 117.146.231.40:34421] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/ofta/tv-20th-annual-television-award-winners
[Wed Apr 12 14:04:16.110538 2023] [autoindex:error] [pid 682372:tid 23391169349376] [client 172.176.188.227:53963] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home2/cinemasi/public_html/ofta/wp-admin/css/: No matching DirectoryIndex (ikonboard.cgi,index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: binance.com
[Wed Apr 12 13:50:50.751573 2023] [:error] [pid 635677:tid 23391192463104] [client 192.185.4.72:0] File does not exist: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/wp-includes/sitemaps/update.php, referer: http://simplesite.com
[Wed Apr 12 13:38:51.917997 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 632200:tid 23391127324416] [client 117.160.250.138:25964] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/ofta/tv-23rd-annual-television-award-nominations, referer: http://www.oftaawards.com/
[Wed Apr 12 13:24:03.573806 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 575380:tid 23391163045632] [client 27.130.69.47:8128] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/ofta/, referer: http://www.oftaawards.com
[Wed Apr 12 13:24:03.080254 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 575380:tid 23391102109440] [client 27.130.69.47:42223] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/ofta/tv-20th-annual-television-award-winners, referer: http://www.oftaawards.com/
[Wed Apr 12 13:08:56.657473 2023] [:error] [pid 535204:tid 23391196665600] [client 185.5.236.208:0] File does not exist: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2020/themes.php, referer: http://simplesite.com
[Wed Apr 12 12:45:01.308142 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 485014:tid 23391114716928] [client 27.130.69.47:10159] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/ofta/, referer: http://www.oftaawards.com
[Wed Apr 12 12:45:00.825677 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 490981:tid 23391102109440] [client 27.130.69.47:36096] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/ofta/tv-20th-annual-television-award-winners, referer: http://www.oftaawards.com/
[Wed Apr 12 12:42:33.312675 2023] [:error] [pid 490981:tid 23391114716928] [client 104.144.83.134:0] File does not exist: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/wp-index.php, referer: http://cinemasight.com/
[Wed Apr 12 12:36:46.167286 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 490981:tid 23391173551872] [client 110.249.201.42:62258] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/ofta/robots.txt
[Wed Apr 12 12:32:46.667553 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 485014:tid 23391186159360] [client 110.249.202.35:28814] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/ofta/
[Wed Apr 12 11:33:57.991790 2023] [autoindex:error] [pid 358400:tid 23391137830656] [client 20.163.8.252:0] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home2/cinemasi/public_html/wp-admin/css/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html.var,index.htm,index.html,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.wml,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.js,index.jp,index.php4,index.php3,index.php,index.phtml,default.htm,default.html,home.htm,index.php5,Default.html,Default.htm,home.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: binance.com
[Wed Apr 12 10:21:37.086327 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 223358:tid 23391226083072] [client 27.130.69.47:44255] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/ofta/, referer: http://www.oftaawards.com
[Wed Apr 12 10:21:36.607288 2023] [access_compat:error] [pid 223357:tid 23391177754368] [client 27.130.69.47:64322] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home2/cinemasi/public_html/ofta/tv-20th-annual-television-award-winners, referer: http://www.oftaawards.com/

I'm also open to just moving my website to another host because this game they play is getting tedious, but that's a LOT of time and effort to get everything moved correctly and will likely become exceedingly expensive.

Comment: You are READY for another hosting company. Good luck.